# SQLAlchemy - Mapping subset of columns from inner join of autoloaded tables

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I've just started using SQLAlchemy to work with an existing Postgres DB. What I'd like to do is autoload two tables, perform an inner join and map a subset of the columns to an object. To accomplish all but the last part, I've written the following code:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapper, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.sql import join, select

engine = create_engine("postgresql://<username>:@localhost/<DBname>")
metadata = Metadata(engine)
Session = sessionmaker(engine)
profiles = Table('userprofile',metadata,autoload=True)
profilefields = Table('profilefield',metadata,autoload=True)
class DBObj(object):
     pass
j = join(profiles,profilefields,profiles.c.fieldid==profilefields.c.fieldid)
mapper(DBObj,j,properties={'fieldid':[profiles.c.fieldid,profilefields.c.fieldid]})
q = session.query(DBObj).all()
```

How should I modify this code to assert that I only want some specified columns mapped to DBObj? I've searched far and wide and can't seem to find an example of how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to map a `select()` with the desired columns.  Mapping a `join()` causes sqlalchemy to turn it into the corresponding `select * from <join>`:

(skip this block: this just creates the test fixture)

```
>>> from sqlalchemy.orm import mapper, sessionmaker
>>> from sqlalchemy.sql import join, select
>>> from sqlalchemy import *
>>> # engine = create_engine("postgresql://<username>:@localhost/<DBname>")
... engine = create_engine("sqlite:///:memory:")
>>> engine.execute(r"""
...     CREATE TABLE userprofile (
...         id integer primary key,
...         fieldid integer,
...         keep integer,
...         discard integer
...     )
... """)
<sqlalchemy.engine.base.ResultProxy object at 0x2390d90>
>>> engine.execute(r"""
...     CREATE TABLE profilefield (
...         id integer primary key,
...         fieldid integer,
...         keep integer,
...         discard integer
...     )
... """)
<sqlalchemy.engine.base.ResultProxy object at 0x2390e90>
>>> metadata = MetaData(engine)
>>> Session = sessionmaker(engine)
>>> profiles = Table('userprofile',metadata,autoload=True)
>>> profilefields = Table('profilefield',metadata,autoload=True)
>>> engine.execute(profiles.insert({'fieldid': 1, 'keep': 2, 'discard': 3}))
<sqlalchemy.engine.base.ResultProxy object at 0x23e9750>
>>> engine.execute(profilefields.insert({'fieldid': 1, 'keep': 2, 'discard': 3}))
<sqlalchemy.engine.base.ResultProxy object at 0x23e98d0>
>>> class DBObj(object):
...      def __repr__(self):
...         return "DBobj" + str(self.__dict__)
... 

>>> j = join(profiles,
...          profilefields,
...          profiles.c.fieldid==profilefields.c.fieldid)
```

Here's the new part:

```
>>> js = select([profiles.c.id,
...              profiles.c.keep,
...              profilefields.c.keep,
...              profiles.c.fieldid,
...              profilefields.c.fieldid],
...             use_labels=True,
...             from_obj=j)
>>> mapper(DBObj,alias(js),properties={'fieldid':[profiles.c.fieldid,profilefields.c.fieldid]})
<Mapper at 0x23e9ad0; DBObj>
>>> q = Session().query(DBObj).all()
>>> q
[DBobj{u'userprofile_keep': 2, u'userprofile_id': 1, '_sa_instance_state': <sqlalchemy.orm.state.InstanceState object at 0x23f08d0>, 'fieldid': 1, u'profilefield_keep': 2}]
```

Comment: Thanks so much. This is indeed helpful.